# What kind of data structure should I use?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, data-structures

Array of Pairs `<string, unsigned long>`

- Array has constant number of elements(`8`).
- Fields `string` filled (not null, PRIMARY KEY), and never change its values.
- Fields `unsigned long` filled with `null` by default, then change its values in runtime.
- There will be a lot of such objects.

Comment: What do the values *represent*?

Comment: How are you intending to use this data?

Comment: Will you have 8 elements or "lot of such objects"?

Comment: Does "there will be a lot of such objects" mean there will be a lot of arrays?

Comment: Context does matter. I think we need more to go on before anyone can give you a good suggestion...

Comment: unsigned long is a value type and can't be null. Perhaps you want the nullable ulong?

Comment: "there will be a lot of such objects" means there will be a lot of arrays, and every array has 8 pairs

Comment: @ Serg Rogovtsev, I'll use it as a class, 8 pairs - an object of this class

Comment: @Jon Skeet, String cityName, nullable ulong - population

Comment: @Steven if i understood you, you need List of array of structs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guess...

```
public class MyData
{
    private Dictionary<string, ulong> _prop1=new Dictionary<string, ulong>(8);

    public Dictionary<string, ulong> Prop1
    {
        get { return _prop1; }
        set { _prop1 = value; }
    }

    public string CityName { get; set; }

    public ulong? Population { get; set; }
}
```

And for the a lot of this:

```
var alotofobject s= new List<MyData>();
```

Edit:

Allright, now I see what you need:

```
var cities=new Dictionary<string,ulong>(8);
cities.Add("City1",0);
cities.Add("City2",0);
cities.Add("City3",0);
cities.Add("City4",0);
cities.Add("City5",0);
cities.Add("City6",0);
cities.Add("City7",0);
cities.Add("City8",0);
```

If you want to set or get the population of a city, just use:

```
cities["City1"]=293238;

var populationOfCity1=cities["City1"];
```

And as a suggestion, please get a beginner book for C#.

Comment: I like when one make a try to answer, even when op are not so sure of how to formulate the question.

Comment: How can I fill in "CityName" and make them constant ?

Comment: like FirstCity, SeconCity.......EightCity

Comment: I just want to make in all generated MyData ojects, all fields already filled in by default, Population is zero and all 8 CityNames is like FirstCity, SeconCity.......EightCity

Comment: I just thought that all Add() methods I can include in implementation of class MyData, and make string field CONST, so it's not allowed to set CityName in runtime

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear rather it is self contradictory. if you want a lot of objects(if you mean many pairs) then you can use a collection `SortedList`. If you have only 8 such pairs then you can use another collection `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make your life simple an define a class that matches your criteria and then make a list of them?

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public long Number { get; set; } 
}

List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

And continue from there adding what you need.